Why do the entropy approach and force approach lead to the same result for the Boltzmann distribution?
In statistical mechanics there are two approaches to derive the Boltzmann distribution:
Entropy approach:
By maximizing the entropy $S$ defined as:
$$
   S = k_B \ln \Omega
   $$
where $\Omega$ is the number of microstates we arrive at the Boltzmann distribution:
$$
   P(E) \propto e^{-E / (k_B T)}
   $$
Force approach:
By considering the system in thermal equilibrium under the influence of a potential $V(\mathbf{r})$, you can use the principles of statistical mechanics to derive the probability distribution by solving
$$
   F(x)n(x)=\frac{dn}{dx}kT
   $$
where the particle density is given by $n=N/V$.
Both approaches seem to yield the same Boltzmann distribution. Could someone explain the underlying reason why both methods lead to the same result even though they appear to approach the problem from different perspectives? Is there a deeper connection between entropy maximization and the mechanical force balance that leads to this consistency?

The expression for the force balance that you wrote down, is strong enough to get to Boltzmann distribution. I mean, why should it have that form?
If you really think harder about the problem, you will realise that it should have very little to do with forces. What you are really doing, is considering the energy (potential energy, at least) approach. Then it is trivial that entropy approach and energy approach will reach the same result, because (constant energy) entropy maximisation is equivalent to (constant entropy) energy minimisation. That is a celebrated theorem in thermodynamics, and is the reason why we can keep playing with the profusion of thermodynamic potentials by minimising them, rather than the equivalent Massieu functions by maximising them.
This is yet another example of why it is just wrong to look at forces in modern physics. It is always energy and momentum that we should be paying attention to. Then the cross-links to other important physics relationships will be laid bare, whereas in forces viewpoint you will just be continually mystified.
